# How can we assess the difficulty of automating the front-end of a web app?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, protractor, watir-webdriver

Are there any general guidelines which demonstrate the difficulty of automating the front end of a web app?

For example, one such guideline could be that all **"critical"** elements have ID attributes whose values don't change frequently. Are there any other guidelines like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very tricky question indeed. I'll give it a shot, but mind you I'm barely going to scratch the surface with this.

**Disclaimer:** What I've written now, especially considering the speed with which the web is moving forward/changing (new **[W3C](https://www.w3.org/standards/)** standards, new frameworks, new levels of abstraction over the same old programming principles), might very well be obsolete or bad-practice in a few years.

---

> 1. **WebElement** locators (my personal take on the matter)

When you gave the example of changing `ids` & `classes` I can't deny I rolled my eyes a bit. But you gave us the first classification:

- QA Automation Engineers that have commit rights on Production Code:

  *We are in the 21st century, in the most technologically progressive era of human-kind and we still feel we should keep the commit rights off-limits for our QAs. Damn!*

  The QA Automation team **SHOULD** create their own set of automation attributes in accordance to a previously **well thought-out** & **documented** strategy.

  The QA Automation team **SHOULD** have the possibility to add/remove/change `IDs`, `classes`, `attributes` in the PROD code, as required by their automation agenda.

  Your `WebElement` mappings **SHOULD** look like this (this is from a `CucumberJS` elements module I wrote):

  ```
  'Device Details of Android phone':'li[connectqa-device="android-phone"] a.detail-button',
  'Device Details of Android tablet':'li[connectqa-device="android-tablet"] a.detail-button',
  'Device Details of iOS phone':'li[connectqa-device="ios-phone"] a.detail-button',
  'Device Details of iOS tablet':'li[connectqa-device="ios-tablet"] a.detail-button',
  'Device Details of Windows laptop':'li[connectqa-device="windows-laptop"] a.detail-button',
  'Device Details of Windows PC':'li[connectqa-device="windows-pc"] a.detail-button',
  ```

  The above `WebElements` have the following qualities: **homogeneous**, **optimized** (no more than 2 tags chained), **scalable**, **dynamic** (the `connectqa-device` attribute's value is generated by `{ deviceType }` in an `ng-repeat` (Angular web app)), **easy to identify**/**use** when writing automated test-cases due to the obvious scheme.

  Your `WebElement` mappings **SHOULDN'T** look like this:

  ```
  'add friend email input error mark':'#scroller-bulk-invite div.form-group.mb10.wrapper.email-f.error div.invalid',
  'add friend name input error mark':'#scroller-bulk-invite div.form-group.wrapper.name-f.error div.invalid',
  'plus button':'#statusStaging div.staging-holder div.devices-staging.ng-isolate-scope ul.actions li'
  ```
- QA Automation Engineers that only have access to the Live Code:

  Here we come to a new pitchfork: do your DEVs want to implement the `WebElement` attributes strategy that your previously **thought-out** & **documented**?

  If **NO**, then you can either try your best to create the best `WebElement` locator strategy with what you have at your disposal.
   If **YES**, then we're in luck. Someone just took a big burden off your shoulders. Now you can concentrate on other things, like optimizing that automation harness.

---

> 2. **Web Frameworks** (especially JS ones)

Most web frameworks nowadays pump a lot of logic into the HTML via different directives/components/decorators/etc. Some of these will be visible to you at different times of the automated test running, or all-throughout the test execution.

**!!! Note:** I greatly encourage you to **stay away** from these when creating your `WebElement` mappings. You are exposing yourself to the following:

- **flaky tests** (Most of these attributes are added via JS at different moments in time, relative to the `$( document ).ready()` marker. If you don't have **serious explicit/implicit waiting** in your methods, expect some **serious** flakiness in your tests);
- **'Element not found'** errors (These directives/components/decorators in today's frameworks are very prone to change. DEVs might just add/change/remove a specific one which you were referring in your mappings and *PUUUFF!*, your regression goes to s@%&.)

  **Example:** (Angular) `.ng-scope`, `.ng-if`, `.ng-click`, etc. These should **NEVER** be in your `WebElement` locator. Else, you're just asking for it!

To be continued ...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Honestly, there is no as such official guidelines which will demonstrate that the front end of a web app is easy to automate or not. But the industry stalwarts in this business have a few recommendation as follows:

1. If your Web Application is built with HTML 5, it had been observed pure Selenium works best with either gecko, chromedriver or IEDriverServer.
2. If your Web Application is built with AngularJS, it had been observed Protector/Jasmine combination works better.
3. Now about the guideline you are expecting `all "important" elements have id attributes whose values don't change "frequently".` is one of the basic requirement. As per best programming practices, all the elements on a Webpage should have an unique `id`, `name` etc attributes. But in real time it have been observed that some elements doesn't have an unique `id` or `name` present in the HTML DOM. At times it have been observed that elements have a dynamic `id`. In these case we may have to think out of box to take help of the other locators e.g. `linkText`, `css` or `xpath` along with `regex` which again would uniquely identify an element.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.